# Rutas raras en el Wordpress localhost (Wordpress Multisite)

Tags: wordpress, url, rutas, localhost

Estoy configurando un wordpress multisite en local
solo he cambiado los urls de los blogs (mini-sitios) en la base de datos, pero me aparece este url raro sobre el botón de menú de Network admin,

¿Alguna idea de como arreglar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el http//localhost, sin los dos puntos
ya lo he buscado por la base de datos y no existe nada como eso allá.

Veo también un enalce raro en el inspector:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con link: ***http://localhost/wp-admin/http://http://localhost/wp-admin/network/***

Puede ser eso que esté mal, que esté mal definida la ruta base del proyecto?
Alguna idea en que tabla arreglar esto?

Muchas gracias,

Carlota

Comment: En wordpress intenta no cambiar valores en las tablas a menos que sepas bien sus efectos secundarios.  Para ese cambio que comentas mejor hacerlo desde el admin de wordpress. Piensa que algunos de los datos de configuración wordpress los serializa en un solo campo, con lo que es dificil encontrarlos y modificarlos a pelo en las tablas.

Comment: gracias, en realidad tuve que hacerlo, pero solo he cambiado los links de los sub-sitios (pasandoles de links de pre-production para rutas locales) ya que eran millares, no podía hacerlos manualmente uno a uno, pero no he tocado en nada rutas nativas de wordpress.

Comment: Si has hecho cambios globales (esos millares que dices) revisa bien lo que has hecho, y para ello, suponiendo que tengas una copia de seguridad de las tablas modificadas, puedes exportar las actuales y comparar los cambios (con un diff, o beyondCompare, o alguna herramienta similar) y ver si realmente se hicieron como pensabas o hay cambios imprevistos (suele suceder en cambios masivos).

Comment: muchas gracias, lo haré